# Why is there a difference between 'docker scale' and 'docker up --scale --no-deps --no-recreate'?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using Docker Compose to spin up and connect 11 Docker containers. As yet, I have not explored Kubernetes (and the like) as I suspect it is a large undertaking that I presently don't have time for. Thus, when my app is finished, I plan to go live with Compose.

Since I am using continuous integration, I expect I will be deploying new containers fairly frequently while the app is in use, so I want to be able to restart containers transparently (so the old container is replaced with a new one with zero downtime). For this purpose I am using Traefik as a front-end proxy, a dynamic file configuration that resets routing rules, and some (PHP) scripts to make the appropriate calls to the `docker` and `docker-compose` binaries.

The theory goes like this:

- Container C1 based on image M1 is running
- Image M2 is built and passes CI
- Container C2 running image M2 is brought up inside Docker Compose (using the scaling feature)
- Traefik is told to switch to the new container C2 instead of C1
- Container C1 is stopped

True, it's a "poor man's orchestration", and yes, I should switch to something that is widely used and tested. But, I have this working, and wish to stick with it for the short term at least.

I am using this version of DC:

> docker-compose version 1.13.0, build 1719ceb

### Up command problem

So, here is the problem I had - how do I create a new instance of a service defined in Docker Compose? My solution was to use scaling, so it would go a bit like this. To scale up `missive-storage-backend`, I would do this:

```
docker-compose -p app -f docker-compose.yml up -d \
    --no-recreate --no-deps --scale missive-storage-backend=2
```

This would leave the existing (old) instance alone and create a (latest) instance that is not connected to anything (i.e. now we have two instances). Great! So, using my custom scripts, I would rewrite the Traefik configuration and the application would continue to operate, using the new component. Finally the old container can be stopped.

That works so far. However, if I now wish to restart something else, things go awry. Let's say I wish to upgrade `missive-interface`. Cool, so I would do this:

```
docker-compose -p app -f docker-compose.yml up -d \
    --no-recreate --no-deps --scale missive-interface=2
```

This has the effect of creating a new instance of Interface, and restarting the previously upgraded container (Storage Backend). I guess this is because Docker Compose recognises that the instance of `missive-storage-backend` is not the one it started with, and so it re-applies the scale=1 rules to it again.

To be fair, the unnecessary restart does not monkey around with the version of the old container (they are both on the latest version). However my script does not expect two restarts, and caters only for one; I could fix that, but frankly it feels like I am patching a leaky bucket.

### Scale command solution

So, I am now trying the `scale` command. The DC manuals say this is superseded by `docker-compose up --scale`, but it behaves differently. Here is the first start command:

```
docker-compose -p app -f docker-compose.yml \
    scale missive-storage-backend=2
```

That works fine, as per last time. Now the start for a new version of the second container:

```
docker-compose -p app -f docker-compose.yml \
    scale missive-interface=2
```

This, correctly, results in a start of just that container, which is what I want. (I then reconfigure Traefik to switch in the new container, then call `docker stop old-container-hash` to bring down the old one).

So, have I misunderstood the purpose of `docker up --scale --no-deps --no-recreate`? Or has my unusual usage of scaling uncovered a bug? It strikes me that I should be be able to scale individual services in DC, without the hassle of copying all my service YAML settings to an individual `docker` command.

Incidentally, I did try a `docker-compose create`, but did not get anywhere with this - it did not create extra instances of the services I wanted, and killed others unexpectedly. Shout up though, if you think that would be a better road to go down.

Finally, I did try "tidying up" after the `up` command, by renaming the old/stopped container and then renaming the new one to the `_1` string it has by default. However, that uncovered a Docker networking bug, so I have abandoned that train of thought!

If it makes a difference, the Docker daemon is running on the host, but I run the DC commands inside a "control" container, by mapping the volume `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` from host to container.

Comment: (I'm seeing a pattern of revenge downvoting and close-voting on my account at the moment. I'll add this temporary note to let folks know what is going on, and will remove it when the close vote ages away).